# Запрос на удаление строки из БД

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Пишу плагин,сделал все что надо было.

```
  global $wpdb;
      $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, url FROM wp_jslider" );
      $rowcount = $wpdb->num_rows;
    if ($rowcount==0) {
        echo 'No images, please upload';
    }
    else {
        for ($i=0; $i < $rowcount; $i++) { 
            echo '<div name="id_'.$myrows[$i]->id.'" class=""><img src="'.$myrows[$i]->url.'" width="100" height="50"><a name="del_'.$myrows[$i]->id.'" href="">x</a></div>';

        }
    }
```

Но не могу удалять конкретную фотографию. Может кто поможет. И скажите, я все правильно сделал во время выборки, а то не хотелось бы безопасность нарушать

Comment: Я в вашем коде не вижу упоминания оператора `delete`. Кстати, `global` - это злющее зло и самый настоящий bad practics

Comment: Добавьте тег `wordpress`, пожалуйста

Comment: rjhdby, Дело в том, что я не в курсе как это осуществить.
vp_arth, Куда, зачем?

Answer (score 0):

> И скажите, я все правильно сделал во время выборки, а то не хотелось бы безопасность нарушать

Неправильно. Не нужно лезть в базу. Нужно пользоваться АПИ.

В данном случае [wp_delete_attachment](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_attachment/)

Answer (score -1):

Общий случай удаления, $wpdb:

```
$wpdb->delete('your_table', array('your_image_id' => $id), array('%d'));
```